# Is there a php ide that can be tyed up to a runtime environment so it can actually aid with code completion for some complex frameworks?

Tags: php, ide

I'm trying to find an php ide that for example can give me hints for all the classes loaded thorough the system load factory ( Codeigniter framework ) . And also can actually assign all properties for controllers no matter how deep the callstack is . This is just an example for those that ever worked with codeigniter .

Comment: If you use any decent IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse, with a decent framework that uses type-hinting like Symfony2, autocompletion will work like a charm. Codeigniter is not complex, it's just bad and old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All IDEs that I have seen (Eclipse, Zend Studio, Netbeans, PHPStorm) rely heavily on correct PHPDoc comments for return values, but if they are present, do a good job at helping with code completion.

Personally, I would suggest using PHPStorm. It does cost you a license, but is well worth the money. It really is a powerful and performant tool.

Comment: +1 vote. The first part is true for ZendStudio too which is also neat (but huge, slooow, and expensive compared to PhpStorm).

Comment: So the only way the built in intelisense sytem could follow up any loaded classes is by documenting them with phpdoc? For all the above ides?

Comment: anyway good info , +1 and will validate soon , maybe more answerers will come

Comment: The IDEs will try to detect stuff automatically, like `return new FooBar()`, which is obvious. But you can also do `$classname = strtoupper($_GET['evil'])."_Wrapper_Class"; return new $classname()`, and this will never be worked out by any IDE, it needs help via PHPDoc comments.